# Pyramidal (not rightangular) stacked barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

Using the following code, I can create a simple stacked barplot that has a rightangular shape:

```
barplot(as.matrix(prop.table(c(150,90,60))),col=c('Cornflowerblue','Yellow','Red'),las=1)
```

The output looks like this

[image]

However, I want to build a barplot that is a pyramid, such that the breakdown of percentages is by its area not by its length. Since the tip of the pyramid has much smaller area than the bottom, the corresponding pyramid plot should look something like this

[image]

I'm just not sure how to code such a plot in R. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably have to write code to compute the vertices of the sections yourself, then call `polygon()` to create the figure ...

Comment: If I did the algebra correctly, the height of an equilateral triangle with area `A` is `sqrt(sqrt(3)*A)` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that will create the points for the polygons for you

```
get_pyramid_layers  <- function(vals, a=1, pad=FALSE) {
  vals <- vals/sum(vals)
  area <- function(y1, y2) {
    .5*(y2-y1)*(2*a-2*sqrt(3)/4*(y2+y1))
  }
  xdist <- function(y) {
    a/2 - y*sqrt(3)/3
  }

  max_height <- a*sqrt(3)/2
  total_area <- area(0, max_height)
  breaks <- rep(0, length(vals) +1 )
  for(i in seq_along(vals)) {
    breaks[i+1] <- optimise(function(x) (area(breaks[i], x)/total_area-vals[i])^2, lower = 0, upper=max_height)$minimum
  }
  padding <- if(pad) {cbind(x=NA,y=NA)} else {NULL}
  as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_along(vals), function(i) {
  cbind(rbind(
    cbind(x=c(-1,1)*xdist(breaks[i]), y=breaks[i]),
    cbind(x=c(1,-1)*xdist(breaks[i+1]), y=breaks[i+1]),
    padding
  ), prop=vals[i], index=i)})))
}
```

I'm not sure it's 100% optimized but it should do the trick. You can make a basic plot in ggplot with

```
library(ggplot2)
vals <- c(.5, .3, .2)
ggplot(get_pyramid_layers(vals), aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(index))) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

That should work with the proportions in any order

```
vals <- c(.2, .1, .3, .4)
ggplot(get_pyramid_layers(vals), aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(index))) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

You could also add the labels with

```
library(dplyr)
vals <- c(.5, .3, .2)
pyramid_data <- get_layers(vals) 
pyramid_labels <- pyramid_data %>% group_by(index) %>% summarize(x=mean(x), y=mean(y), prop=first(prop)) 
ggplot(pyramid_data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(index))) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(prop, accuracy=1)), data=pyramid_labels, color="white") + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

And if you want to use base graphics, you can do

```
vals <- c(.5, .3, .2)
plot(c(-.5, .5), c(0, .85), type="n")
with(get_pyramid_layers(vals, pad=TRUE), 
  polygon(x,y, col=c('Cornflowerblue','Yellow','Red')))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, looks like it does the trick. Any way to do do this without using ggplot?

Comment: @Oposum I made a small change to make it easier to use with base plots and added an example of using it at the end.

Comment: thank you very much - yes this is it. One last thing, how can I add percentages to it?

Comment: one last thing, how can I add percentage values in base graphics?